# What's the difference between Top-Down (Tree), Top-Down (Heavy) and Bottom-Up (Heavy) in Chrome's Trace Event Profiling Tool

Tags: node.js, profiling, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I am trying to use Google Chrome's [Trace Event Profiling Tool](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool) to analyze a Node.js application I am running. Once I have selected a sample of points, I can choose between three views:

- Top-Down (Tree)
- Top-Down (Heavy)
- Bottom-Up (Heavy)

What are the differences between these views? What do they each represent? Which is the most useful view to look at from a profiling perspective?

Comment: Google has documentation here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/js-execution?hl=en 

Although to be honest, it isn't very clear

Answer (score 1):

- **Top Down (Tree)**  When you want to view the root activities that cause the most work, use the.(Call tree)
- **Bottom-Up (Heavy)** When you want to view the activities where the most time was directly spent on each function.
- **Top-Down (Heavy)** I am just guessing for this one I think its the inverse of Bottom-Up (Heavy) so the function that took the most overall time including sub functions.